# How to capture error message from prompt - shell or perl

Tags: perl, shell

I am trying to capture the output of a command. It works fine if the command executes. However when there is an error, i am unable to capture what gets displayed in commandline

Eg.

```
$ out=`/opt/torque/bin/qsub submitscript`
qsub: Unauthorized Request  MSG=group ACL is not satisfied: user abc@xyz.org, queue home
$ echo $out

$
```

I want $out to have the message

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors are on stderr, so you need to redirect them into stdout so the backticks will capture it:

```
out=`/opt/torque/bin/qsub submitscript 2>&1`
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
    # By convention, this is sent to stderr, but if you need it on
    # stdout, just remove the >&2 redirection
    echo "Error: $out" >&2
else
    echo "Success: $out"
fi
```

You should test the exit status of the command to figure out what the output represents (one way shown). It is similar for perl, slightly different syntax of course.

Comment: There is a reason that errors are sent to stderr, and that should be respected.  Errors belong on stderr: `echo "Error: $out" >&2`

Comment: As a general rule, yes. I don't know what the OP's requirements are so I chose not to confuse the issue. In a few cases merging things into stdout is useful for further processing or logging. I'll edit the answer to make the options clear.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing it like this

```
$ out=`/opt/torque/bin/qsub submitscript 2>&1 > /dev/null`
$ echo $out
```